# Wowza or Red5 hosting for minimal usage

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, hosting, red5, wowza

I'm getting into selling Flex webcam recorder applications. Such applications send streams to either wowza or Red5 servers for saving and playing back the streams.

I'm running into an issue regarding setting up a server to demonstrate the functionality of the applications to the users online.

Two things to consider :

- I don't have much money to spend on expensive media hosting services
- The streaming-server usage will be minimal as it will only accept small non-frequent streams from users trying the application on my website.

Any media hosting services I can use? will http://www.slicehost.com work in my case ?
Will it be a better(cheaper) solution if I can setup my own streaming server ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the cheapest solution is to install your own server. But you'll still have to buy a Wowza license ($55/month).

I have used [Wowza for EC2 (devpay)](http://www.wowza.com/pricing/ec2-streaming#embedded-license) for about 2 years now. With a m1.small instance it costs ~$110/month for the server plus some extra depending on traffic. But if you use it just for demos, the traffic costs should be very low.

For Red5 you pretty much have to install it on your own on another server.  silcehost.com works for this.

The cheapest of all, would be to install them both (Wowza and Red5) on the same server, on different listening ports. This will cut the costs down to server(usage+traffic) and Wowza license.